# deleting m4a after merging youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to download a playlist from youtube but I always have this problem:

> youtube-dl download video, sound and merge.

But when it tries to delete the rest, there is no progress.

```
[fishticker@archsamsung F1.4]$ youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKlJrMyWAE0&list=PLBD47CE9F15D97BEC
[2] 3822
[fishticker@archsamsung F1.4]$ [youtube] cKlJrMyWAE0: Downloading webpage
[youtube] cKlJrMyWAE0: Extracting video information
[youtube] cKlJrMyWAE0: Downloading DASH manifest
[download] Destination: J-doe  - #iongivafuhabownuhn (I Don't Give A Fuck About Nothing)-cKlJrMyWAE0.f137.mp4
[download] 100% of 54.17MiB in 01:29
[download] Destination: J-doe  - #iongivafuhabownuhn (I Don't Give A Fuck About Nothing)-cKlJrMyWAE0.f141.m4a
[download] 100% of 5.28MiB in 00:04
[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "J-doe  - #iongivafuhabownuhn (I Don't Give A Fuck About Nothing)-cKlJrMyWAE0.mp4"
Deleting original file J-doe  - #iongivafuhabownuhn (I Don't Give A Fuck About Nothing)-cKlJrMyWAE0.f137.mp4 (pass -k to keep)
Deleting original file J-doe  - #iongivafuhabownuhn (I Don't Give A Fuck About Nothing)-cKlJrMyWAE0.f141.m4a (pass -k to keep)
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 8):

This is a shell problem not a youtube-dl issue, since the url contains a `&` character you have to quote the url:

`youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKlJrMyWAE0&list=PLBD47CE9F15D97BEC'`

otherwise youtube-dl only gets `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKlJrMyWAE0`(you can check this by running youtube-dl with the `--verbose` option).
There is more info in the [youtube-dl README](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/eb6cb9fbe934fe99a35af22065cf91063d416c12/README.md#video-url-contains-an-ampersand-and-im-getting-some-strange-output-1-2839-or-v-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).